# How to manually set the color as the second one of the theme in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry if my question is somehow confusing, don't hesitate to edit it.

I'm comparing 2 sets of data and I'm now creating plots.

On some plots, I can show both groups and ggplot automatically add some pretty colors, in my case red for the first group, and blue for the second one.

My problem is that on other plots, I have to show either one group or the other, and so the color is always red.

**How can I manually ask ggplot to fill my plot with the second color of the theme ?**

Here is some dummy code if you like :

```
df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
                 f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("young","old")),
                 boxthis=rnorm(100))

#both groups on the graph, 2 colors (red and blue) :
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + geom_boxplot() 

#each group on one graph, both the same color (and I'd like one red and one blue)
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = "m"), data = df) + geom_boxplot()
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = "w"), data = df) + geom_boxplot()

#I know the grouping is incorrect, this is just an example where I keep the same df
```

Comment: Wouldn't manually settings a palette or colors solve the problem?

Comment: yes, it would, but I have a lot of plots so it would be tedious.

Comment: I dont get your question, Do you want your individual groups in blue?

Comment: No, I want one red and one blue, the same colors that ggplot used in the first grouped plot.

Comment: `ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = "m"), data = df) + geom_boxplot(fill = '#F8766D')`
`ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = "w"), data = df) + geom_boxplot(fill = '#00BFC4')`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I ask. If my supervisor suddenly wants me to change the theme, I'd have to manually change all colors. I want to use the theme colors and select the 1st or the 2nd depending on the case

Comment: "Themes" don't have fill colors in ggplot, "scales" do. But the color of the scales varies with the number of groups. You will really need to define your own palette somewhere and then reference those colors explicitly. Should be easy to do with a `scale_fill_manual`

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, I'll resign to this !

Comment: Maybe you can make it works with `ggplot_build` using the first graph and getting the colors for the second

Answer (score 0):

Are facets what you're looking for?  Try this:

```
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_grid(~ f1)
```

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCW0g.png)